# Eclipse Oxygen no puede abrirse usando Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

El 21 de septiembre de 2017 apareció Java 9 de manera oficial. Quiero probar lo nuevo que ofrece Java, principalmente ese aclamado sistema de módulos. Acabo de instalar Oracle JDK 9 en mi equipo y Eclipse Oxygen que tiene un plugin para soportar el desarrollo en Java 9 (al 22 de septiembre 2017 en beta). Todo bien, ya instalé las herramientas, pero al ejecutar el Eclipse veo que aparece un mensaje de error y no puedo ver mi espacio de trabajo. Aquí la imagen del mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento ver el contenido del mensaje del error pero me parece muy extraño lo que dice:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-22 01:30:39.845
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/annotation/PreDestroy
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
>           at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot
>   be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>           ... 21 more

¿Qué puedo hacer para ejecutar Eclipse con el JDK 9 instalado en mi equipo?

Comment: Jo, ¡qué prisas que tienes! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Independiente del sistema operativo, lo que debes hacer es ubicar el archivo eclipse.ini<sup>1</sup> de tu instalación de Eclipse y agregar la siguiente línea:

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

Con eso se podrá ejecutar Eclipse sin problemas, pero con los paquetes elementales para ejecutar una aplicación Java de consola.

Para poder implementar cualquier tipo de aplicación Java con Eclipse, puedes agregar la siguiente configuración:

```
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Fuente: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

---

<sup>1</sup> En Windows y Linux, el archivo eclipse.ini se encuentra en la carpeta de instalación de eclipse. En MacOS, el archivo eclipse.ini se encuentra dentro de Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse.